# A confusion on $\beta\eta$-reduction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, definition, computer-science, lambda-calculus

Recently I've started exploring lambda calculus, and currently I'm tackling the next exercise:

> Prove that if $M =_{\beta\eta} N$, then $FV(M) = FV(N)$,

Where $FV(P)$ stands for free variables in the term $P$. Obviously, $\eta$-conversion doesn't affect on the free variables, since $\lambda x.Mx =_\eta M$ exactly when $x \notin FV(M)$, and $FV(\lambda x.Mx) = FV(M)$ when the same condition holds.

But what about $\beta$-reduction? It's obvious, that if $M \to_\beta N$, then $FV(N) \subseteq FV(M)$. It's also known that $\beta$-reduction can eliminate free variables, as said [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1344398/does-beta-eta-reduction-preserve-free-variables) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2408184/is-a-lambda-term-alpha-equivalent-to-its-beta-reduction). How then it might be possible that $FV(M) = FV(N)$ for the stated condition? The simple example $(\lambda x.y)z \to_\beta y$, and thus $(\lambda x.y)z =_\beta y$ breaks the statement. Maybe there's a typo in the exercise?

Or maybe I don't quite understand the difference between $\beta$-reduction and $\beta$-equivalence: as far as I understand, if $M \to_\beta N$, then $M =_\beta N$, and the latter, the $\beta$-equivalence, just means (by Church-Rosser) that $\exists L$ such that $M \twoheadrightarrow_\beta L$ and $N \twoheadrightarrow_\beta L$. But this facts, as I suppose, can't help me to resolve the issue.

Seems obvious that there exists such $M$ and $N$, that $M \twoheadrightarrow_\beta N$, but the converse doesn't hold. And still it's said that $M =_\beta N$. Thus $\to_\beta \subset \twoheadrightarrow_\beta \subset =_\beta$ should hold. Then, again, I don't get how the statement in the exercise above holds.

Can anyone give a hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a link to the source of this exercise? Maybe there is some implicit background hypothesis that makes the statement true. Otherwise the statement is obviously false.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco, the exercise is originally in russian from the lecture notes, in russian: `Докажите, что из M =βη N следует FV (M) = FV (N)`, which is precisely the statement above.

Also, can you give an example of the hypothesis with which the statement is true? The only I can find is something like `any λ-term with syntax λx.M should have x in FV(M)`, so the case `λx.y` is not applicable anymore

Comment: There is a Turing-complete fragment of the $\lambda$-calculus where the statement is true: the $\lambda I$-calculus. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically answered the question yourself. Clearly, the statement is false.  More precisely:

- It is *true* that if $M =_\eta N$ then $FV(M) = FV(N)$, for the reason you wrote in your post.
- It is *false* that if $M \to_\beta N$ (and so, if $M \twoheadrightarrow_\beta N$, or $M =_\beta N$, or $M =_{\beta\eta} N$) then $FV(M) = FV(N)$, for the reason you wrote in your post.
- It is *true* that if $M \to_\beta N$ (and more generally, if $M \twoheadrightarrow_\beta N$) then $FV(N) \subseteq FV(M)$; the proof is a straightforward induction on the definition of $M \to_\beta N$.
- If $M =_{\beta} N$ (and so, if $M =_{\beta\eta} N$) then we cannot say much about  the relation between $FV(M)$ and $FV(N)$. For instance consider $M = (\lambda x.y)z$ and  $N = (\lambda x.y)z'$, with $z \neq z'$: then, $M =_\beta N$ (and so $M =_{\beta\eta} N$) and $FV(M) = \{y,z\} \neq \{y,z'\} = FV(N)$, but $FV(M) \not\subseteq FV(N)$ and $FV(N) \not\subseteq FV(M)$.

There is a restriction of the $\lambda$-calculus where the statement "if $M =_{\beta\eta} N$ then $FV(M) = FV(N)$" becomes true: the [$\lambda I$-calculus](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/16508/36283). This fragment of the $\lambda$-calculus is obtained by adding the constraint that in a term of the form $\lambda x. M$, necessarily $x \in FV(M)$, that is, terms such as $\lambda x.y$ are not allowed. Roughly, this fragment doesn't allow terms where one abstracts over a variable but doesn't use it. This way, the counterexamples to $FV(M) = FV(N)$ are impossible to build in the $\lambda I$-calculus.
The $\lambda I$-calculus is interesting because, despite its restrictions, it is still [Turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).

---

As an aside comment, note that if a statement of the form "$A$ implies $B$" *holds* and $A'$ is a *particular* case of $A$, then the statement  "$A'$ implies $B$" *holds* as well. Dually, if a statement of the form "$A$ implies $B$" *fails* and $A'$ is a *generalization* of $A$ (i.e. $A$ implies $A'$), then the statement  "$A'$ implies $B$" *fails* as well.

Concretely, once you established that the statement "if $M \to_\beta N$ then $FV(M) = FV(N)$" is false, it automatically follows that also the statements "if $M \twoheadrightarrow_\beta N$ then $FV(M) = FV(N)$" and "if $M =_\beta N$ then $FV(M) = FV(N)$" and "if $M =_{\beta\eta} N$ then $FV(M) = FV(N)$" are false.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! But isn't there a typo in the 3rd bullet? I thought the set-inclusion is in the another direction (so, $FV$ behaves contravariant), e.g. the example $ (\lambda x.y)z \to_\beta y $ shows, that $FV(y) = y \subset FV((\lambda x.y)z ) = \{y, z\}$.

Comment: For the aside comment, yeah, I understand this, but I thought that there's probably something that I don't get, since I haven't thought that there's a flaw in the exercise, but the mystery is easily solved. Anyway, thanks again for the details!

Comment: @PaulSnopov - Of course, there is a typo, the inclusion is on the other way round. Fixed. Thank you for spotting it.